# Why Xcode detects my iPhone 7 plus device as iPhone 5 with wrong screen scale and size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cgsize

I run my app on my iPhone 7 + device and when I try to log the Scale and screen bound sizes, What I get is related to iPhone 5/5s/5c/SE, NOT to my iphone 7 plus specification.
This is what I get in log:

```
CGFloaf scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
CGFloat screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

NSLog (@"Scale: %f", scale);
NSLog (@"screenHeight: %f", screenHeight);

Output :
Scale: 2.000000
screenHeight: 568.000000
```

Why is that??! I appreciate any help.

Comment: what version of the SDK and Xcode are you using?

Comment: Because you don't have a proper launch screen or you don't have the proper launch images.

Comment: My launch images have the right pixel size and also as file name, I tried both `Default-414w-736h@3x~iphone.png`  and 
`Default-736h@3x.png` but still it doesn't work. I use XCode 9.2

Comment: Im affraid I would probably have the same problem with iphone X as well. Could you suggest me the correct names for launch images so I can assure it will detect Plus size devices as well as iPhone x correctly? I appreciate it.

Comment: Also all devices including iPads and normal sized iphones are working correctly, These are the names I have for my launch images for each device:

Default-568h@2x.jpeg
Default-667h@2x.png
Default-736h@3x.png
Default-812h@3x.png
Default-Portrait@1x.jpeg
Default-Portrait@2x.jpeg

Comment: @Reza.Ab You don't need any special filenames for the launch images. As long as you are properly using a launch image set in Xcode, the filenames are irrelevant.

Comment: I am already using launch image set and all sizes are correct! @rmaddy

Comment: Apparently not. Show some screenshots from Xcode showing that your launch images are setup correctly.

Comment: here is a picture @rmaddy https://imgur.com/a/j1cYC

Comment: go to interface builder click on you vc click and drag your view to your vc give equal height and width. i hope it may be help

Comment: @JRB omg are you being serious?

Comment: @Reza.Ab whats wrong Buddy?

Comment: @JRB of course Ive done all sort of stuff with launch screen and set constraints and stuff but if i wanted to so that i wouldn't use Launch image set.  I don't want to use Launch screen xib because putting an imageview in it won't detect Launch images for iPhone x. So that's pointless